# Unable in Intelij Idea to see files in hidden Linux (dotted name) directories

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, hidden-files

When in Intelij Idea I try to see diff between files located in hidden directories (outside the project) like .hiddenDirectory, then Idea doesn't show such directories in dialogue box. The Finder (it is MacOS) shows that files - I set it up accordingly. Idea - not.
How to see them in Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command + shift + . in Finder dialog may help

Comment: Found the reason why this dd not work in my case - other key combination overlapped this one